# How to await for the response of Alert dialog in React Native?

Tags: react-native

From my observation, the `Alert` dialog seems built on top of the React Native app.
So it pops out everytime you call it, and doesn't to be in the `render` function.
The catch is it is not an async task so the code after `Alert` will continue to execute regardless the callback function.

The code below demonstrates a situation where the `Alert` dialog keeps popping out because it reads the same barcode over and over again.
(It is written in TypeScript. Just take my word, this is a valid snippet.)

```
 import * as React from "react";
 import Camera from "react-native-camera";
 import { Alert } from "react-native";

 export default class BarcodeScanSreen extends React.Component<any ,any> {
 private _camera;
 private _onBarCodeRead = e => {
    if (e.type === "QR_CODE") {
        Alert.alert(
            "QRCode detected",
            "Do you like to run the QRCode?",
            [
                { text: "No", onPress: this._onNoPress },
                { text: "Yes", onPress: this._onYesPress }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
        );
    }
};

 private _onYesPress = () => { /* process the QRCode */ }

 private _onNoPress = () => { /* close the alert dialog. */ }

render() {
    return (
        <Camera
            onBarCodeRead={this._onBarCodeRead}
            aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
            ref={ref => (this._camera = ref)}
        >
            {/* Some another somponents which on top of the camera preview... */}
        </Camera>
    );
}
}
```

Is there a way to pause the JS code and await the response from `Alert`?

Comment: The simplest way would be to store a flag if the Alert is showing, and reset it to false when it is dismissed.

Comment: I had similar idea in mind. But `onBarCodeRead` function still runs constantly in background to check the flag. I wonder if there is better way to handle this.

Comment: Hey, I just edited my answer because I published https://github.com/slorber/react-native-alert-async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert does not pause the code. In this case JS is not the only problem - the `Camera` component also keeps running in the background which is native and it will trigger the `onBarCodeRead` listener, regardless if the Alert is present or not.

You could try to stop the camera at the beginning on `_onBarCodeRead` with the `stopPreview()` method mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RCTCamera.md#stoppreview).

Also note that `react-native-camera` is currently in a migration process from `Camera` (`RCTCamera`) to `RNCamera` and in the new `RNCamera` I don't see a `stopPreview()` method. Anyhow, a simple flag would also do the job.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. `stopPreview()` is deprecated in `RNCamera` module. I noticed that, sometimes `Alert` interrupts with the `_onObjectDetected` in `RNCamera`, so the barcode scanning feature completely stops after dismissing the dialog.

Answer (score 38):

React-native Alert doesn't stop the execution of code below it. By changing it to async function which resolves the promise on user action will work as ASYNC-Alert.

```js
const AsyncAlert = async () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  Alert.alert(
    'info',
    'Message',
    [
      {
        text: 'ok',
        onPress: () => {
          resolve('YES');
        },
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
});

await AsyncAlert();
```

Comment: Yes it does. Tested.

Comment: 'await is only valid in async function', was this just recently changed? Most answers show something similar but none of these code samples actually run. Need to wrap the await in its own async function, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

### Use [react-native-alert-async](https://github.com/slorber/react-native-alert-async)

I've just published a package that does exactly this and permit to await for the choice of the user. It is compatible with Expo.

```
 import AlertAsync from "react-native-alert-async";


 const myAction = async () => {

   const choice = await AlertAsync(
     'Title',
     'Message',
     [
       {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => 'yes'},
       {text: 'No', onPress: () => Promise.resolve('no')},
     ],
     {
       cancelable: true,
       onDismiss: () => 'no',
     },
   );


   if (choice === 'yes') {
     doSomething();
   }
   else {
     doSomethingElse();
   }

 }
```

---

**Original answer:** I've made a PR to ReactNative for this feature: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/20312

Comment: tripped into this problem again when I try to build a custom dropdown menu for react-naviagtion navbar. I will give it a try, thanks a lot

Comment: Works great @SebastienLorber . Your package helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Do you think https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997495/2007055 is much better?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution.

The trick used here is to make a function that calls the button's `onPress` function, then resolve the promise with the index of the button. Note that this requires the alert to be uncancellable.

```js
showAsyncAlert = (title, message, buttons, options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // We can't detect a cancellation, so make sure the Alert is not cancellable.
    options.cancellable = false
    buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
      let onPress = button.onPress
      button.onPress = option => {
        if (onPress) {
          onPress(option)
        }
        resolve(index)
      }
    })
    Alert.alert(title, message, buttons, options)
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
let option = await showAsyncAlert(title, message, buttons options)

if (option === 0) {
    foo()
} else {
    bar()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some workaround for this,If you have alert function like below

```
     Alert.alert(
                'Delete comment?',
                'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?',
                [
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                        style: 'cancel',
                    },
                    { text: 'yes', onPress:() => this.props.deleteComment(commentId),
                ],
                { cancelable: false },
            );
  //call after comment is deleted
  refreshPage();
```

This code does not wait for alert's response, it will execute `refreshPage()` immediately.

so, you can do something like

```
         Alert.alert(
                    'Delete comment?',
                    'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?',
                    [
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                            style: 'cancel',
                        },
                        { text: 'yes', onPress: async () => {await this.props.deleteComment(commentId);refreshPage();},
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false },
                );
```

Comment: I ended up having the function where I display my alert in a Promise and the `onPress` callback is calling `resolve`. Thanks for the inspiration 

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return a promise:

```
const asyncAlert = (title, message, callback) => (new Promise((resolve) => {
    Alert.alert(
        title,
        message,
        [{ text: "Cancel" }, { text: "OK", onPress: () => resolve() }], { cancelable: false }
    );
}).then(callback));
```

Usage:

```
return asyncAlert("My Title", "Are you sure?", () => SOME_PROMISE_FUNCTION())
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-async-alert

Use this npm. Which is same like the above answer of @Makatun, but in easy and reliable way.

```
  import {AlertProvider} from 'react-native-async-alert';
  import {useShowAlert} from 'react-native-async-alert';

  function App() {
    return (
      <AlertProvider>
        {/* Content */}
      </AlertProvider>
     );
  }
```

And simply use it like this. You can customize your alert also.

```
  import {useShowAlert} from 'react-native-async-alert';
  const result = await showAlert({
    title: 'Title',
    text: 'text',
  });
  console.log(result);
```