# How can I make a Switch component async await for successful response before changing value?

Tags: javascript, react-native

The default flow of a switch will toggle the value as soon as it is pressed.

I want to execute the following logic

1. Press switch
2. **Don't change the value yet**
3. Open alert box
4. If ok, send post request to toggle database value
5. On successful response, allow the switch value to change

I can get the successful response and update the switch, but as soon as I press the switch the value toggles twice and I want to pause this behaviour until there is a successful response. Tried async await, tried wrapping the switch in a touchablewithout feedback... now need some help

```
<Switch 
   value={this._getSwitchValue(id)} 
   onValueChange={() => this._toggleSwitch(id)}
/>

  /**
   * Toggle the Switch - Send post request to database
   */
  _toggleSwitch (id) {
    Alert.alert('Notice!', 'Do you really want to change this setting?',
    [
      { text: "OK", onPress: () => this.props.toggleSettingsSwitch(id, this.props.token) },
      { text: "Cancel", onPress: () => console.log("cancel pressed")}
    ],
    { cancelable: true }
  )}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809762/how-to-await-for-the-response-of-alert-dialog-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Switch` value inside the function that makes the request.

```
toggleSettingsSwitch = async (value) => {

  const response = await this.changeSettingsRequest(); // making a call

  // here add a check, if request was successful change switch value
  // if (response.ok) {
  // this.setState({ switchValue: value });
  //}

};

_toggleSwitch = (value) => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Notice!',
    'Do you really want to change this setting?',
    [
      {
        text: 'OK',
        onPress: () => {
          this.toggleSettingsSwitch(value);
        },
      },
      { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('cancel pressed') },
    ],
    { cancelable: true }
  );
};

<Switch
  onValueChange={this._toggleSwitch}
  value={this.state.switchValue}/>
```

[snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/change-switch-after-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanks, but that snack example has the exact same problem. The switch still gets executed when its pressed. Also worth noting that I can dealing with several switches on a settings pages and I need to pass ID param

Comment: Yes, it's an example based on your needs change it, I've added comments to my answer to guide you.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem in the snack example persists. As soon as the switch is pressed, it turns on and then off. I want the switch to remain set until the value is actually changed

Comment: you mean the little animation happening after you pressed? that's the actual behavior of `Switch` you can't change it.

Comment: The switch doesn't even turn on, since the value doesn't change, the switch remains off.  What you see is the on press animation, which happens when you click the switch.

Comment: Surely there is a way to disable that animation and keep it from changing until the value actually changes??

Comment: No, when I press the switch on the snack example I see 3 animations. I only want 1.

Comment: which three animations?

Comment: The animation you want to remove is built into the OS, on press effect is by default going to fire, we can only change the state of the switch, `On| Off` but we can't change the default behavior. When you press the switch it's going animate but if the value is false it will remain off.

Comment: @Dazzle looks like you don't how `Switch` works, the example given above works as you expected, yes the `Switch` has on press animation but it doesn't turn on, it remains off from the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for people still looking for an answer to this, try: [react-native-switch-pro](https://github.com/poberwong/react-native-switch-pro)

Another alternative is to create your own async-supporting switch-like component, here's an example on snack: [Custom Async Switch](https://snack.expo.dev/@michael-gridio/custom-asyncswitch-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can just have another variable `loading` and ignore calls, if it is true

```
_toggleSwitch = async (value) => {
  if (this.loading) {
     return;
  }
  this.loading = true;

  try {
     ...
  } finally {
     this.loading = false;
  }
};
```

You can even put it in React state and make it part of UI interaction (hiding Switch if it's in loading state and presenting some kind of animation)

I would just optimistically update UI state and inform user in case of an error, that way UI would feel more responsive.